# javascript/angular - can not get the exact return response data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Good day!

I just signed up stackoverflow and made this question as I have been scouring this problem through searching this massive and awesome site. Unfortunately, their questions and solutions doesn't seem to help me.

Here is my short js code:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope,$http,$window) {

...[more codes]...

$scope.callMeMaybe = function(coverImageId) {
  var THUMBNAIL_URL = './thumbnails/' + coverImageId;
  var THUMBNAIL_DATA_URI = new String('data:image/jpg; base64, ');
  var result = new String('');

  $http.get(THUMBNAIL_URL).then(function successCallback(response){
    var data = response.data;
    result = new String(THUMBNAIL_DATA_URI.concat(data));
    $scope.loaded = true;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.loaded = false;
    if ( response.status === 403 ) {
      $window.alert('You are forced logged out');
      $window.location = '/login/';
    } else {
      $scope.elementBindingError();
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
  return result.valueOf();
};

... [some more codes] ...
}])
.directive('myDirective', function(){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.attr('src', scope.callMeMaybe(attrs.thumbnail));
  }
}
});
```

I cant seem to get the concatenated response data from callMeMaybe function.
That directive is part of my <img> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you have a ajax call take care of what you are returning, If its dependent on the ajax success result then you have to return the result from within the success callback itself or else how do you expect the success result to be returned without the success being called. So the prototype should be something like below

```
        $scope.callMeMaybe = function (coverImageId,functionCompleteCallBack) { //pass a new function into this, with this function we will set the element src

        // ... your other stuff

        $http.get(THUMBNAIL_URL).then(function successCallback(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            result = new String(THUMBNAIL_DATA_URI.concat(data));
            $scope.loaded = true;

            functionCompleteCallBack(result.valueOf()); //You need to execute the function passed as a callback.

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.loaded = false;
            if (response.status === 403) {
                $window.alert('You are forced logged out');
                $window.location = '/login/';
            } else {
                $scope.elementBindingError();
            }
        });           
    };

}])

           // ... your other stuff

.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.callMeMaybe(attrs.thumbnail, function (elementSrc) { //note that we are passing a new function and set the element src inside this callback function
                element.attr('src', elementSrc);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any confusions.

Comment: Yea. I just realized that it was called asynchronously. I just output logs on before and after. 
I understood what you explained. 
I'll try your solution and get back if I have some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably happening because of the asynchronous call. The return of `callMeMaybe` is happening before you get the data. You should only return `result` when successCallback/errorCallback is called. Also, make sure the scopes are all right - couldn't see that part without the HTML.

Comment: Yea. I just realized that it was called asynchronously. I just output logs on before and after.